# How to clean up file location contents

Tags: c#, file-io

I have a method which goes to a database, get some byte arrays back and then my gui displays this by creating a new windows form object and callinging a method on that form , passing in the list of bytes to display.

The thing is the gui i am calling from is in control of where the files are written, i want the location cleaned on the closing of the display form.

I could pass a file path into the contrcutor of the imagedisplay form but this to me doesnt really make sense. How else can i solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you creating files in the first place?

Comment: Are you saving files to disk or control does it? At which point would you like files to be deleted?

Comment: i am displaying returned pdf's as thumbnails to the users, there could be 1 any number of pdfs available. i write them to a temporary directory to keep a handle on which thumbnail has been clicked. Essentially the files should be removed when the form closes so essentially the form whcih displays the pdf thumbnails should clean up in the form close event. However the display clase has no knowledge of the file location unless i pass it in to the constructor. This doesnt seem like the right thing to do tho

Answer (score 0):

Add to the Form's Closing event.  If your using VisualStudio you can do this.Closing += (and it'll auto-populate the event for you) in your constructor or _Load() event and then do your file cleanup in the Closing method that you create to handle the closing event.

Comment: i am displaying returned pdf's as thumbnails to the users, there could be 1 any number of pdfs available. i write them to a temporary directory to keep a handle on which thumbnail has been clicked. Essentially the files should be removed when the form closes so essentially the form whcih displays the pdf thumbnails should clean up in the form close event. However the display clase has no knowledge of the file location unless i pass it in to the constructor. This doesnt seem like the right thing to do tho. Do you suggest calling the delete event at the end of the constructor and why?

Comment: You need to store the locations someplace.  Why not have a class that does it, and hook up a method to it that cleans up on its deconstructor.  Make it a global variable of your form and when its done being used, the Form will close and the GC will call the deconstructor of the class that is holding the list of the files.  It'll do its cleanup and then be collected.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be writing the byte arrays to file to begin with if you can prevent it. From your description, it sounds like you can simply pass it the byte array in memory.

Comment: i am displaying returned pdf's as thumbnails to the users, there could be 1 any number of pdfs available. i write them to a temporary directory to keep a handle on which thumbnail has been clicked. Essentially the files should be removed when the form closes so essentially the form whcih displays the pdf thumbnails should clean up in the form close event. However the display clase has no knowledge of the file location unless i pass it in to the constructor. This doesnt seem like the right thing to do tho

Comment: @ricki: It sounds like this could all be done without writing the files to disk (unless you are using some third party app that can only read files from a file).